# How to design 433 MHz RF with SYN470R?

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, 433mhz

In this document, I see that 50 Ω of the antenna is mentioned, but what makes me wonder is that in the table below, each strange frequency has a separate impedance, Zin.

1. What is Zin and what does it mean?
2. Each Zin has 1 L in series and another L in parallel, so what are these 2 L values for? Or just take it for impedance matching?

When I design an antenna and impedance matching, do I need to consider Zinc or just have an impedance of 50 Ω?[image]

Comment: In this document, I see that 50 Ohm of the antenna is mentioned, but what makes me wonder is that in the table below, each strange frequency has a separate impedance, Zin. 1: What is Zin and what does it mean? 2: Each Zin has 1 L in series and another L in parallel, so what are these 2 L values for? Or just take it for impedance matching? When I design an antenna and Impedance Matching, do I need to consider Zinc or just have an impedance of 50Ohm?

Comment: Hi there! Would be so kind and add the datasheet into your otherwise well formulated question? Also, I believe your comment is redundant :)

Comment: Why do you refer to "Zinc"? Please link the data sheet so it can be read as context.

Comment: https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/453934_1928180.pdf

Comment: link datasheet , page 13